# Есть ли смысл писать return после исключения?

Tags: c++

Представим ситуацию, когда есть какая-то функция которая принимает в себя аргумент и возвращает результат. В её коде есть проверка этого аргумента на различные значение. И если аргумент равняется недопустимому значение - будет брошено исключение. Так вот, нужно ли после исключения писать return? Или в этом нет никакого смысла?

Пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

size_t checkpls(size_t value)
{
    if (value == 123)
    {
        throw exception("bad number((");
        return SIZE_MAX; // Нужно ли это?
    }
    cout << "all ok" << endl;
    return 23421;
}

int main()
{
    cout << checkpls(123);
    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Непонятно, где именно вы хотите писать `return`. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Может и есть смысл, а может и нет. Смотря что возвращать и что делает функция.

Comment: @Harry добавил пример

Comment: команда `throw` работает также как `return` только другим скрытным путём.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нет, в этом нет никакого смысла.

Comment: А если у человека отключены исключения, что тогда?)

Comment: @ComeInRage Тогда `throw` уронит программу, вроде как?